# My LED lamp is blinking. Could the power supply be the issue?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led

I have a lamp that I received without power supply. It is pretty simple, just three LEDs and a switch. The device wants a 13V, 700ma power supply. I've had some 12V supplies with 1.25A that worked for a little bit, but did get the lamp/heatsink for the LEDs really hot and started blinking.

Now it blinks as soon as I turn it on. I'm trying to understand what is going on here.

Did the LEDs basically run the power supply too hard and break it? Is there a better explanation of what may be going on here?

Is the only real solution to the keep it from happening to provide the proper 13V or could I add some resistance with the result of slightly dimming it or something else?

Am I correct that having more Amperage isn't a big deal in this scenario if I can find that 13V?

What should I expect if I plugged the 12V rail from a modified PC power supply into it?

If all this is overly simply stuff for this community, please point me in the direction of where these questions might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Had this blinking with some 12V LED lamps, too. Turned out they didn't like the old 12V switching power supply which obviously was made for halogen bulbs only. Replaced that supply, all okay now.

Electronic background: 12V LED lamps (mostly single-chip ones) have a small switching power supply inside them, too, as the LED wants 350mA constant current at ~4V. So it's one switching supply working on another and that failed. Overcurrent because the LED bulbs draw current only in a spiky fashion.

Comment: Then some additional decoupling may help - a few hundred microfarads maybe.

Comment: Usual 12V halogen switching transformers are 9.5kHz AC on output. So I had to make a 2A 9.5kHz rectifier bridge from some suitable diodes first. *Dislike.* 25W LED power supplies cost about 15€ incl. shipping.

Comment: Oh OK I didn't realise most switchers for halogen left their output as AC but that does make sense. Then my comment is nonsense.

Comment: The blinking made me crack open that stupid supply and see (and measure) the mess. Then I checked some other halogen supplies and found they are all such cheapo stuff.